# SelectList method MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

**Problem Description:** 
I am using ASP.NET MVC and I have the following method in my Controller Class. This method uses SelectList method to select a list of items from the database. These items will then be passed to the view to be displayed in a drop down list.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    Album album = db.Albums.Find(id);

    ViewBag.ArtistId = new SelectList(db.Artists, "ArtistId", "Name", album.ArtistId);
    return View(album);
}
```

**My Understanding of the selectMethod:**

I know that the first param takes a list of items.
The third param is the property to be displayed.In this case, we will be displaying the name property of the Artists.
Based on my research, I found out that the 4th param is the default value that will be displayed on the dropdown list.

**My Question:**

1) I would like someone to help me understand about the second param.

2)Since we are displaying names of the artists, how can we display a default artist name in the fourth param using Artist ID?

I hope you guys understood my questions. I would be happy to clarify them to you if you need me to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The second parameter is the name of the "value" property or field on each element in the first parameter. Since two artists could conceivably have the same, it's generally better to use an ID column (as in the example) so that you know specifically which item was selected.
2. In the example, you are providing the artist of the currently-viewed album as the default to appear. Assuming that `db.Artists` includes an artist whose `ArtistId` property matches the given value, the rendered HTML will produce a select list where that artist is selected.

Did that answer your questions?

Comment: So just to be sure am on the same page. The reason behind the second param is that we might have two artists with the same name and that's why we need the ID to differentiate them. So when I click the edit button, the code will select the value(which is an ID of the name)I selected,and then it will match it with the ID in the fourth param to display the artist's name. Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492553%28v=vs.108%29.aspx):

The first parameter is an `IEnumerable` of objects from which to construct the list.

The second parameter is the name of the object property (for each object in the list) to be used as the `value` attribute of each rendered HTML `<option>` element.

The third parameter is the name of the object property (for each object in the list) to be used as the `text` attribute of each rendered HTML `<option>`.

The fourth parameter is the default selected `value` (which indicates the element of the list that will be rendered with the `selected` attribute).